# How to find element that match a certain string with Xpath?

Tags: regex, xpath

I would know if it's possible to find all elements that match a certain string, using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath).
For example, suppose I have this page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
    </form>
    <p class="test"></p>
    <p class="test"></p>
    <p class="test"></p>
    <p class="test"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

If I search for this string`<form id="form1">` I would get the first form element, instead if I search for this string `<p class="test"></p>` I would get all the paragraphs elements. Is it possible? 
Something like `//*[matches(., string)]`
I'm at the beginning, so any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Pattern or entire string? It's not clear.

Comment: @revo sorry, I mean string.

Comment: And what is the language / environment you work with?

Comment: @revo java and in particular I'm using htmlunitwebdriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Try this using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) :

```
//form[@id="form1"]
```

#### Output :

```
<form id="form1">
</form>
```

#### The rest :

```
//p[@class="test"]
```

and if you want a *partial match* :

```
//p[contains(@class, "tes")]
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I wuold made it general, not restriceted to this case. Suppose I don't know the structure of the page and I want find if an element match a pattern. Is it still possible?

Comment: This is general, read about _xpath_ : `//` is for _recursion_

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the question. I would find all elements that match a string.

Comment: Check _partial match_ addition